# Get current value of a webelement in selenium after clicking a button

Tags: selenium, qwebelement

I have a web page in which there is an input field containing text "0" (when the page loads). There is a button in the page. When I click it, there is a small function that runs and the text in the aforementioned field changes to "20". But, when I try to get the element value, I still get "0", i.e., the same value before clicking the button.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="0" data-bind="value: ShippingTotal() == '0' ? '0' : ShippingTotal()" disabled="">
```

How can I extract the true value from the input field?

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: driver.findelement(By.xpath("//input").getAttribute("value"); i dont understand what is complicated about this if you did try what i shared please put what you tried and the html of the page

Comment: Sorry for the late response,
https://www.anipet.co.il/delivery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that although '20' is entered into the field, the "value" attribute still remains '0'.

Try this:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("[YOUR_PATH_HERE]")

elem.get_attribute("innerHTML")

print(elem)
```

You could double click the field and copy the value.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import pyperclip

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("[YOUR_PATH_HERE]")

actions = ActionChains(driver)

actions.double_click(elem).perform()

elem.send_keys(u'\ue009', 'c') # This is CONTROL + C

text = pyperclip.paste()
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, thanks for the reply. It helped mer answer